# The weekend graph didnt show up as the code. How to print both graph : weekdays and weekend respectively

Tags: r, csv

Here's [a link for the data from the github called activity.csv]: https://github.com/sefakilic/coursera-repdata/blob/master/project1/activity.csv

**The task is to print out the two graphs showing the different pattern between weekdays and weekend``
but there is only one graph about weekdays shown after running this code**

```
    data <- read.csv("activity.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',', colClasses = c("numeric", "character",
                                                                       "integer"))

data<- data_full 



data_full <- mutate(data_full, weektype = ifelse(weekdays(data_full$date) == "Saturday" | weekdays(data_full$date) == "Sunday", "weekend", "weekday"))
data_full$weektype <- as.factor(data_full$weektype)
head(data_full)
##       steps       date interval weektype
## 1 1.7169811 2012-10-01        0  weekday
## 2 0.3396226 2012-10-01        5  weekday
## 3 0.1320755 2012-10-01       10  weekday
## 4 0.1509434 2012-10-01       15  weekday
## 5 0.0754717 2012-10-01       20  weekday
## 6 2.0943396 2012-10-01       25  weekday

interval_full <- data_full

  group_by(interval, weektype)

  summarise(steps = mean(steps))


s <- ggplot(interval_full, aes(x=interval, y=steps, color = weektype)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~weektype, ncol = 1, nrow=2)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

After running it, there's a couple of things wrong with your code.

First, you incorrectly assign data_full (empty) to data via `data <- data_full`.

Second, you are attempting to use `weekdays()` without first converting the date from character to date using `as.Date()`.

Third, your calculation of steps is off - it should not be reading over 800. This is causing your chart to look off. This might have to do with how you handled imputing the values. I'm not going to try to fix this one for you. Check out the mice package for a full selection of how to handle imputed values.